# How to convert this C# script to native C++?

Tags: c++, sorting, keyvaluepair

I'm beginner in C++. Before I work with C#. Bellow is a C# script. How I can do same these things in native C++?

All I need is:

- A list, or similar, have int-int key-value pair
- Can auto sort by value. If not, it must be sortable by key and it can get index of a
  value (each of my values is definite)

I tried `std::map` but it don't have built-in sort by value or get key by value. Is C++ have similar thing like `sortedlist` in c#?

Thank you very much!

```
public static SortedList<int, int> sortedList1 = new SortedList<int, int>();

static void List_Add(int i) // 0 < i < 1000
{
    if (!sortedList1.ContainsValue(i))
        sortedList1[Environment.TickCount] = i;
}

static void List_Remove(int i) // 0 < i < 1000
{
    if (sortedList1.ContainsValue(i))
        sortedList1.RemoveAt(sortedList1.IndexOfValue(i));
}

static int List_toInt()
{
    int time = 0;
    int keys = 0;
    bool modifier = false;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> i in sortedList1)
    {
        if (i.Value > 90) modifier = true;
        if (i.Key - time > 200 | modifier | keys > 1000)
        {
            keys = keys * 1000 + i.Value;
            time = i.Key;
        }
    }
    return keys;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be doing the wrong way round as usually things are sorted using keys and queries are done using the key not using the value. However, it seems a `std::map<int,int>` will help you here. Simply use your value as a key of the map and your key as value(so that you can query using the value). Use multimap if duplicates are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

This are some converter tools:
Please visit the following links:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/convetercpptocs/
- http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/CSharp_to_CPlusPlus_Converter_Details.html
- http://cscpp.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Like that:

```
#include <map>
#include "Winbase.h"

std::map<int, int> sortedList1;

void List_Add(int i) // 0 < i < 1000
{
    if (sortedList1.find(i) == sortedList1.end())
        sortedList1.insert(std::make_pair<int, int>(GetTickCount(), i));
}

void List_Remove(int i) // 0 < i < 1000
{
    if (sortedList1.find(i) != sortedList1.end())
        sortedList1.erase(sortedList1.find(i));
}

int List_toInt()
{
    int time = 0;
    int keys = 0;
    bool modifier = false;
    for (std::map<int, int>::const_iterator it = sortedList1.cbegin(); 
        it != sortedList1.cend(); it++)
    {
        if (it->second > 90) modifier = true;
        if (it->first - time > 200 || modifier || keys > 1000)
        {
            keys = keys * 1000 + it->second;
            time = it->first;
        }
    }
    return keys;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How to function `List_Remove`? Because seem map dont have built-in find by value?

Comment: in `List_Add`, make check if have key exist, dont change it value!

Comment: If sortedList1 have pair (1, 1000) Your `List_Remove(1000)` find key 1000, not find value 1000.